# How apply chosen to jQuery UI datepicker select box?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-chosen

Does anyboady know how style select box which appear on top of  [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) calendar:

```
$('.input-field').datepicker();
```

with [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

I try apply it to select inside **ui-datepicker-div** but with no luck.

**[here is code to play](http://jsbin.com/udelok/2)**

Does anyboady know how to do it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solves it. :)

Extend the datepicker's _updateDatepicker function with the concept offered in my previous response.

```
var updateDatepickerOriginal = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(){
  var response = updateDatepickerOriginal.apply(this,arguments);
  this.dpDiv.find('select').chosen();
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Very nice, now I need to figure out what the heck `var response = updateDatepickerOriginal.apply(this,arguments);` does

Answer (score 1):

**Almost** works: Once the input field is clicked, apply .chosen() to each select. :)

```
$("#the_date_input_field").click(function(event){

    $("#ui-datepicker-div select").each(function() {
        $(this).chosen();
    });

});
```

[**View demo!**](http://jsbin.com/udelok/8/edit)

Choosing a month seems to reset the whole calendar.
So, really need a way to extend the initialization so that chosen is applied inherently.

Comment: It's working but it would be great to have some callback function in jQuery UI.